# Change links on all pages according to PHP

Tags: php

Ok my website incorporates different languages, I did:

```
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : "";

if (!empty($lang)) {
    $curr_lang = $_SESSION['curr_lang'] = $lang;
} else if (isset($_SESSION['curr_lang'])) {
    $curr_lang = $_SESSION['curr_lang'];
} else {
    $curr_lang = "he";
} 


  if (!empty($pb20_14users->language == he)) {
    echo "&lang=he";
  }

if (file_exists("languages/" . $curr_lang . ".php")) {
    include "languages/" . $curr_lang . ".php";
} else {
    include "languages/he.php";
}



// Returns language key
function lang_key($key)
{
    global $arrLang;
    $output = "";

    if (isset($arrLang[$key])) {
        $output = $arrLang[$key];
    } else {
        $output = str_replace("_", " ", $key);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

The text has changed and everything is perfect, but I want to change my URL
&lang=he

But don't go through all the existing pages manually, they were built like this:

```
<div class="links">
        <a href="?page=home">Home</a><br />
        <a href="?page=register">Register</a><br />
        <a href="?page=statistics">Statistics</a><br />
        <a href="?page=forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>  
    </div>
```

How do I make all addresses end & lang = he without going through one by one, if it matters I made a table in SQL called language and there is the word he, maybe it will help the thinkers, thank you very much

Comment: can't you assume that value unless you get a different value from url?

Comment: You mean you hard-coded the same menu into multiple pages / script files, instead of outsourcing that into an include file to begin with? Then now would be your chance to fix that mistake :-) If you don’t want to do that, then you’ll have to resort to using output buffering to catch the final output at some point, and then manipulate the links in there (DOM parsing, or via regular expressions.)

Comment: I see the <sql> tag, but where's the SQL?

Comment: What I want to get at the end of the score XXX.com/??page=home&lang=he
No need to go now and change URL everywh

Comment: Just change links on all pages with desired values, page and language.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you go a (basic) nice url system, your urls will become `/en/?page=foo` which isnt the biggest rewrite in the url.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*) /$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

I havent tested that line, but it should be close. We take everything before the slash (`en`) and add that to the rest (`?page=foo`) which results in `?page=foo&lang=en` for your script.

---

Now you can do this and use `CURRENT_LANG` everywhere in your PHP for the language.

```
$lang = in_array($_GET['lang'], ['en', 'nl']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en';
define('CURRENT_LANG', lang);
```

Or try to use the `<base />` tag in html.